# how to draw part of the image with libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

```
int img_w = 100;
int img_h = 50;

TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, img_w, img_h);
batch.draw(region, 0, 0);
```

Wouldn't it draw the full image and

```
TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(texture, img_w / 2, 0, img_w / 2, img_h);
batch.draw(region, 0, 0);
```

the half of it?

Where I am wrong? Or there is a better solution to draw a half of image?

Comment: you're not wrong that is the right side of your texture :) what is the problem ?

Comment: I think the problem is in scale, going to check it.

Comment: thanks for confirming that my code is right :)

Comment: img_w = texture.getWidth() / 2 ,same with the height to get the exact size of your textures

Comment: the problem was in scaling, thanks )

Comment: Answer your own question so other people can benefit from it if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot about scaling.
The original image size was 100x50, but on display it should be 50x25 and after drawing a portion of a texture I need to recount new display size.